# this._verify is not a function on NestJS custom Strategy

Tags: node.js, nestjs, passport.js, nestjs-passport

The NestJs application is giving me this._verify is not a function when trying to implement a custom passport strategy.

I followed the guidelines as per the nest Documentation and would like to know if I am doing something wrong in the implementation. I was able to implement the Local and JWT strategy however not able to implement this.

Following is the error stack:

```
[Nest] 508  - 02/12/2022, 1:52:39 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] this._verify is not a function
TypeError: this._verify is not a function
    at LocalStratergy.Strategy.authenticate (D:\projects\capp\node_modules\passport-custom\lib\strategy.js:60:8)
    at attempt (D:\projects\capp\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:369:16)
    at authenticate (D:\projects\capp\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:370:7)
    at D:\projects\capp\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:91:3
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at D:\projects\capp\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:83:83
    at LocalAuthGuard.<anonymous> (D:\projects\capp\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:49:36)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\projects\capp\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:17:58)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
```

Following is the custom strategy code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-custom';

@Injectable()
export class CustomStratergy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {


  async validate(req: Request): Promise<any> {
    const valid = true;
    if (!valid) throw new UnauthorizedException();
    return true;
  }
}
```

This is how I register it in the NestJS application:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { UserModule } from '../user/user.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { CustomStratergy } from './stratergies/custom.stratergy';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { JwtStratergy } from './stratergies/jwt.stratergy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secret', 
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1d' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, CustomStratergy, JwtStratergy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Also the AuthGuard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class CustomAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('custom') {}
```

I have gone through other similar error articles on SO and was not able to resolve the error even after following them. So if anyone can help it will be much appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case I had a constructor and I was providing an unnecessary configuration to super. The issue was solved by simply calling `super()` without any argument.

For the sake of it, could you try to add an empty constructor ?

```
constructor() {
    super()
}
```